# How to get data from DB using query param?

Tags: java, postman, endpoint

My DB data is

```
-----------------------
id     |   value     |    
-----------------------
1      |   a,b       |
-----------------------
2      |    c        |
-----------------------
3      |    d        |   
-----------------------
```

I am trying to get DB values using this endpoint: http://localhost:8996/abc/v2/tpids?values=a,b...

```
String[] tpids = apiData.request.getParam(constants.tpids).split(",")

abc/v2/tpids?values=a,b,c,d this case was failed... it treated a,b,c,d as comma separated values –
```

In this case, a and b as treated two different values
but I need [a,b] as treated single value... How to escape comma form param value...  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the splitting is redundant, and you just need to treat the entire input as a single string:

```java
String tpids = apiData.request.getParam(constants.tpids);
```

Comment: abc/v2/tpids?values=a,b,c,d    this case was failed... it treated a,b,c,d as comma separated values

Comment: @AlexSparrow That API doesn't make sense. With an API like that you have no way of knowing if you're looking for a, b, c and d as four different strings; a, b and c,d as three different strings or even a,b,c,d as a single string